# C# and Linq launching combined Linq query

Tags: c#, linq

Is it possible to execute a combined Linq query as a some sort of query in c#?

For example I've got 3 methods:

```
private queueCollection;

private void testA(parameterA)
{
    if(parameterA != null)
    {
       queueCollection.Add(someCollection.Where(a => a.Name = parameterA))
    }
    else
    {
      queueCollection.Add(someCollection);
    }
}

private void testB(parameterB)
{
    if(parameterB != null)
    {
       queueCollection.Add(someCollection.Where(b => b.Name = parameterB))
    }
    else
    {
      queueCollection.Add(someCollection);
    }
}

private void testC(parameterC)
{
    if(parameterC != null)
    {
       queueCollection.Add(someCollection.Where(c => c.Name = parameterC))
    }
    else
    {
      queueCollection.Add(someCollection);
    }
}

public void linqQueue()
{
    start queueCollection;
}
```

So can I query different combination at once and don't need to code every combination separately?

I want to create a sorting filter on the collection so if I'll get parameter A, I will get A results from collection; if I add B, I want A and B, and if I get A null I want B only etc.

Comment: Please can you rephrase this question? It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: All three of those methods are identical.  They just use different names for the method, parameter and lambda argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your question correctly, the answer is Yes, you can. You can use Predicates in Linq queries.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void test(parameterA,parameterB,parameterC)
{
    queueCollection.Add(someCollection.Where(a => (parameterA != null && a.Name = parameterA) && (parameterB != null && a.Name = parameterB) && (parameterC != null && a.Name = parameterC)));
}
```

or if you need OR operator

```
private void test(parameterA,parameterB,parameterC)
    {
        queueCollection.Add(someCollection.Where(a => (parameterA != null && a.Name = parameterA) || (parameterB != null && a.Name = parameterB) || (parameterC != null && a.Name = parameterC)));
    }
```